# From the Html Agility Pack download, which one of the 9 "HtmlAgilityPack.dll" do I use?

Tags: html-parsing, html-agility-pack

There are nine folders in the downloaded zip file for HTML Agility Pack:

- Net20
- Net40
- Net40-client
- Net45
- sl3-wp
- sl4
- sl4-windowsphone71
- sl5
- winrt45

I do not know what these folder names mean. Please explain which one I need in order to scrape data from html files using VS2010.

Please explain where I should put the files.

Comment: The folder names represent which version of .net the DLL was compiled for.  If your using VS2010, use the DLL in the Net40 folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The different versions are compiled against different .NET framework versions. Some frameworks, such as the WinRT or the Silverlight frameworks, have more limited functionality or require slightly different (and often slower) approaches to implement the features of the component you're using.

You will want to use the HTML Agility Pack version that best matches your applications. So:

- net20: .NET 2.0 and 3.5
- net40-client: .NET 4.0 client profile
- net40: .NET 4.0 full profile (incl server binaries)
- net45: .NET 4.5
- sl3-wp: Windows Phone 7.0
- sl4: Silverlight 4.0
- sl4-windowsphone71: Windows Phone 7.5
- sl5: Silverlight 5.0
- winrt45: Windows 8 Modern UI App

When you want to use the component with multiple apps, choose the lowest common denominator.